# Overflow:auto only certain div on container resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Right now I have following structure:

[image]

When the browser re-sizes resulting in decrease in container height I want only the list (#content) to have `overflow-y:auto` as follows:

[image]

But as of now, the div resizes but the content doesent, it remains where it is and flows out of container when its re-sized.

Here is the code:

```
        body,html{
            height:100%;
        }
        #container{
            font-size:1em;
            background-color:#ffffff;
            max-height:60%;
            max-width:25%;
            min-height:10%;
            margin-left:5%;
            margin-top:5%;
            margin-bottom:5%;
            padding:.5%;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-width:5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

        }
        #content{
            overflow-y:auto;
        }
```

and this:

```
        <div id="container">
            <span id="logo">
                <img alt="logoImg" src="logo2.gif">
            </span>
            <div>
            <h4>Some Awesome Recipie</h4>
            <ol class="content">
            <li>Chocolate</li>
            <li>Bananas</li>
            <li>Quuie</li>
            <li>Rasa Berries</li>
            <li>Biscotie</li>
            <li>Juliette Brownies</li>
            <li>Red Apple</li>
            <li>More Chocolate</li>
            </ol>
            <span id="tip">
            Other extras can be: Sprinkes, almonds, anything sweet.
            </span> 
            <a href="#" class="downloadLink">Download</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is a working JS fiddle of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/DeH2F/6/

Comment: That's the normal behaviour: you have text inside your div, so the browser just puts a scroll bar to show it. It's not capable of resizing text

Comment: are you looking for something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/DeH2F/ ??

Comment: This is happening because of the current screen's resolution. so try to use different css for media with low screen resolutions.. or try using a fixed with.

Comment: @NathanLee Thanks, But thats exactly what I had tried earlier but it applies scroll for the entire container. I want it only for the `<ol>`

Comment: Well in that case, Keep this <ol> in a <div> and apply the same overlay:auto to that <div>

Comment: No, I tried it, doesnt work,Here it is:  http://jsfiddle.net/DeH2F/4/

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
  #content{
  height:100%;
   max-height:auto !important;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove max-height in #container

Comment: With that, the container doesnt resize atall with change in browser height

Answer (score 0):

Different Screen Resolutions may differ your View Port.

For example, 
Just assume your systems DPI (Dots per Inch) is 75dpi.
Which can adjust only 10 images of some size in the current screen width.

And when you watch the same image in some other system which is having 96dpi, may fit the same image in 10 - 20 copies in the current screen resolution.

In those scenarios you have to follow some cases to achieve this.

Case 1: you have to read the current dpi from the screen resolution and calculate the actual screen resolution and use that one. Which is indefinite way to achieve this.

Case 2: Stop giving the width in %'gs.. This is not at all a good solution to achieve your goal.

Case 3: The Final and definite way to achieve your goal is to provide individual css for different media queries.

I hope this may help you.. For more details about media queries in css.. follow this link

[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

[Media Queries](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have knowledge about Media queries and responsive designs. But the fact that this is a very small part and has to be kept to the minimal code. I was looking for a solution that doesn't make use of media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this

```
ol.content {
   overflow-y: auto;
   max-height: 20%;    
 }
```